# Powershell Column Removal Script - SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I have a csv file that has multiple lines of text and columns. I want to write a script that will assign each column a variable from a single row one at a time and move to the next row. Basically, what should happen is that the first column should be stored as URL, the second as list and the third as field and then perform these tasks. Then move to the next row.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb (Your site URL)
$list = $web.Lists[“Your List Name”]
$field = $list.Fields[“Your Column Name”]
$field.AllowDeletion = “true”
$field.Sealed = “false”
$field.Delete()
$list.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

I can do it line by line, but I would like to find out a better way to do this. I've tried writing code a number of ways, but I can't figure out how to do this with a "foreach" loop. Please help.

Comment: Can you give a CSV example, Then I perhaps hepl you.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the format of the CSV fields, it's hard to say for sure but something like this might work in terms of adapting your code (assuming here you have csv column names of URL, List and Column):

```
$csv = import-csv C:\yourpath\yourfile.csv
$csv | select * | foreach {
    $web = Get-SPWeb ($_.URL)
    $list = $web.Lists[$_.List]
    $field = $list.Fields[$_.Column]
    $field.AllowDeletion = “true”
    $field.Sealed = “false”
    $field.Delete()
    $list.Update()
    $web.Dispose()
}
```

I can't test the sharepoint elements but importing the csv (if it has a header row) then iterating through each object/row using a foreach loop will work.

Importance of header row is that Import-CSV will automatically create a NoteProperty named for each heading that you can then use to access that value in the current object/row.